# How to receive Content-Type multipart/related response using java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, saaj

I am using SAAJ Soap connection to call the third party web service.It seems that web service have been created using WCF or C# .When i am invoking my URL using SOAP UI tool its working fine and receiving response successfully. When i tried to access through below java code i am receiving error.

Code :

```
public class SOAPClientSAAJNew {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();        

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "XXX";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

        // print SOAP Response
        System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");
        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);

        soapConnection.close();
    }
}
```

Error:

> SEVERE: SAAJ0008: Bad Response; Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"'.
>   Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (415Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"'.
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:148)
>           at example.SOAPClientSAAJNew.main(SOAPClientSAAJNew.java:25)
>   Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (415Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"'.
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:258)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
>           ... 1 more

CAUSE:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (415Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"'.
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:258)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
        at example.SOAPClientSAAJNew.main(SOAPClientSAAJNew.java:25)
```

In SOAP UI tool in the headers part i could see Content-Type i am receiving as

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 35512
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:02b574c6-30b8-45f3-a9fc-5d5deac849ab+id=14";start-info="application/soap+xml"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 10 Sep 2014 12:55:29 GMT
```

How to receive this content type using java ? I have tried using axis also. Same error message i have received .

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-binary_Optimized_Packaging

Comment: https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr067/SAAJ1_3ChangeLog.html#getAttachment